# Attribute update via CSV not reflected on Layered Navigation

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation

I am trying to import updated attribute values (including multi-select) via csv. The import runs okay, and the record is updated correctly. But it is not reflected on the Layered Navigation.

I need to re-save the record via admin to get it to display correctly.

Would appreciate help on this.

Comment: you have to rebuild your indexes and clear the cache

Comment: clear cache and check

Comment: I have cleared cache, and re-build the indexes. Does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say I've come across this before and that the issue was that the imported CSV wasn't attributed to the store properly. Try checking the CSV to be sure the store ID or similar is included... Also did you run the indexer after the import?

Comment: The CSV includes the _product_websites value, but not the store ID (_store). I tried adding the store name value, did not work.